# Regression component tests with Cucumber. Is there any boundary to the layers that should be tested?

Tags: java, cucumber, integration-testing, regression-testing, hexagonal-architecture

I found myself last week having to start thinking about how to refactor an old application that only contains unit tests. My first idea was to add some component test scenarios with Cucumber to get familiarised with the business logic and to ensure I don't break anything with my changes. But at that point I had a conversation with one of the architects in the company I work for that made me wonder whether it was worth it and what was actually the code I had to actually test.

This application has many different types of endpoints: rest endpoints to be called from and to call to, Oracle stored procedures and JMS topics and queues. It's deployed in a war file to a Tomcat server and the connection factory to the broker and the datasource to the database are configured in the server and fetched using JNDI.

My first idea was to load the whole application inside an embedded Jetty, pointing to the real web.xml so everything is loaded as it would be loaded from a production environment but then mocking the connection factory and the datasource. By doing that, all the connectivity logic to the infrastructure where the application is deployed would be tested. Thinking about the hexagonal architecture, this seems like too much effort having in mind that those are only ports which logic should only be about transforming received data into application data. Shouldn't this just be unit tested?

My next idea was to just mock the stored procedures and load the Spring XMLs in my test without any web server, which makes it easier to mock classes. For this I would be using libraries like Spring MockMvc for the rest endpoints and Mockrunner for JMS. But again, this approach would still test some adapters and complicate the test as the result of the tests would be XML and JSON payloads. The transformations done in this application are quite heavy where the same message type could contain different versions of a class (each message could contain many complex object that implement several interfaces).

So right now I was thinking that maybe the best approach would be to just create my tests from the entry point to the application, the services called from the adapters, and verify that the services responsible to send messages to the broker or to call other REST endpoints are actually invoked. Then just ensure there are proper unit tests for the endpoints and verify everything works once deployed by just providing some smoke tests that are executed in a real environment. This would test the connectivity logic and the business logic would be tested in isolation, without caring if a new adapter is added or one is removed.

Is this approach correct? Would I be leaving something without testing this way? Or is it still too much and I should just trust the unit tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application and environment sound quite complicated. I would definitely want integration tests. I'd test the app outside-in as follows:

- Write a smoke-test suite that runs against the application in the actual production environment. Cucumber would be a good tool to use. That suite should only do things that are safe in production, and should be as small as possible while giving you confidence that the application is correctly installed and configured and that its integrations with other systems are working.
- Write an acceptance test suite that runs against the entire application in a test environment. Cucumber would be a good choice here too.

  I would expect the acceptance-test environment to include a Tomcat server with test versions of all services that exist in your production Tomcat and a database with a schema, stored procedure, etc. identical to production (but not production data). Handle external dependencies that you don't own by stubbing and mocking, by using a record/replay library such as [Betamax](https://github.com/betamaxteam/betamax) and/or by implementing test versions of them yourself. Acceptance tests should be free to do anything to data, and they shouldn't have to worry about availability of services that you don't own.

  Write enough acceptance tests to both describe the app's major use cases and to test all of the important interactions between the parts of the application (both subsystems and classes). That is, use your acceptance tests as integration tests. I find that there is very little conflict between the goals of acceptance and integration tests. Don't write any more acceptance tests than you need for specification and integration coverage, however, as they're relatively slow.
- Unit-test each class that does anything interesting whatsoever, leaving out only classes that are fully tested by your acceptance tests. Since you're already integration-testing, your unit tests can be true unit tests which stubb or mock their dependencies. (Although there's nothing wrong with letting a unit-tested class use real dependencies that are simple enough to not cause issues in the unit tests).

Measure code coverage to ensure that the combination of acceptance and unit tests tests all your code.

Comment: For what I understand, this approach would be the opposite of what I was told to be honest. I understand the idea of writing first the use cases using a BDD approach and that was what I wanted to do. But wouldn't adding an acceptance test suite running in a real environment take to long to test the application? My understanding is that you would want to have a test suite that testes your business logic without relying on any external system(BBDD included)to speed up things. Having proper component tests that verify your logic would only leave the test in a real environment to verify the wiring

Comment: That's why I suggested just adding up to the current unit tests a suite of tests written using BDD style that would verify all the different use cases available but only from the application services onwards. The unit tests should test any conversion done from port to application so any new port added would be unit tested in isolation, not needing to update any test case if this happened. The smoke test run after is deployed should verify the wiring, that external services are working as expected and that the ports are reachable. Is there anything wrong or missed by using this approach?

Comment: Regarding running in a real environment (I presume you mean a test environment, not production), I wouldn't expect acceptance tests to take too long, although I also wouldn't expect them to be as fast as unit tests. I'll clarify that there should only be as many as necessary. I did say that you should isolate them from external dependencies. Regarding their purpose, testing the wiring (integration testing) is exactly the point. And regarding the purposes of acceptance tests and smoke tests, it's much better to find your integration errors in testing than in production.

Comment: I actually think we're mostly on the same page. We may have some confusion due to misunderstanding about what each of us considers an external dependency.

Comment: I think the differences are in the environment used to run the tests. My idea is to provide a test suite that can be run without having to deploy to any environment and requiring any connection to a database. Mocking every port would allow for fast regression tests while still verifying all the business logic. This could be run as part of any CI job prior to deploy the artifact to nexus and locally in the developers computer. After that, it could be deployed to a test environment to run any smoke test or acceptance test required to verify integration to all the systems.

Comment: Summarizing:
 - Unit tests for any edge cases, complex logic, data transformation or routing (spring integration or camel).
 - Component tests to verify business logic mocking every port so transformation from or to ports to application is not tested here.
 - Acceptance tests to verify, once deployed to a test environment, that it integrates correctly with any external service. This would test core functionality.
- Smoke tests in a production environment to verify nothing is broken.
Does this make sense?

Comment: Regarding your first comment since my previous one, I would hold out for a test environment with Tomcat. Overall, I'd want the test environment to be as similar as possible while still fitting on a developer's machine. If your application writes directly to a database, I'd hold out for having that in your test environment. Database interaction is too complex for me to be confident in testing it with test doubles.

Comment: Regarding your next comment, I'm unclear whether your component tests are the same as my acceptance tests. By acceptance tests I mean tests that test the entire application except for dependencies you don't own (not just a component of your application). I do think you need those to catch errors in your regular test cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think I have a more clear idea of how to tackle this now. We definitively need to improve our test suite so we'll try to add test scenarios to verify our logic in a test environment. 
Thanks again!